# Recursion problem : operating( 5!=1*2*3*4*5 etc....)

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I tried to input 3, and it would be perfect if it stoped here(picture below), but it kept running for two more steps and turned out outputting 3

```
a=1
k=0
def factorial(num):
    
    global a
    if num !=k:
        
        a=a*num
        factorial(num-1)
    else:
        return a
        

factorial(int(input()))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B239A.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Do you want `return factorial(num-1)` instead?